# moodle authenticate the user by username and password - web service

Tags: integration, moodle

I was looking for a way to authenticate a user on my site against moodle web service.

It seems that there is no web service that recives username and password and returns the user data.

Is it possible to overcome this ? i need to authenticate a user on my wp site against the moodle system

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something like an SSO using a Moodle system, then it is not possible to authenticate from Moodle.

However, you can have a common external authentication system such as OpenLDAP or OpenID and authenticate both Moodle and Wordpress from the OpenID application.

If you would like to get the user information from Moodle, then you could use the External Services API to get it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So according to what you say , if i want to integrate an external website to moodle , i must manage users credentials on an external systems ?